# Linux: For "tail -f filename", does the follow read lines only after a \n?

Tags: linux, bash, file-io

```
Initial File:
line 1
line 2
line 3

File after append 1:
line 1
line 2
line 3
lin

File after append 2:
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

If I do a "tail -f filename", and then the file gets updated as above,

Does tail follow on with updates of half a line, or does it only return atomic lines?

i.e.

Am I guaranteed to see/not-see "lin" after append 1?
If there is no \n after "line 4", will I see it?

In particular, I'm interested in whether I can read atomic lines. I'm running a log monitoring application, and I only want to parse complete lines. The log files might be updated to half a line, and if tail doesn't guarantee atomic lines, I will have to guard against that (i.e. read char by char and then identify a line when I see the \n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my mac (`9.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 9.8.0`) the built-in `tail` shows characters appended to the file. Here is a small test:

```
import sys, time

def write(fname):
  fd = open(fname, 'wb')
  try:
    while True:
      for i in range(0, 5): 
        fd.write('a')
        fd.flush()
        print >>sys.stderr, "Wrote a char"
        time.sleep(2)
      fd.write('\n')
      fd.flush()
      print >>sys.stderr, "Wrote newline"
      time.sleep(2)
  finally:
    fd.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  write(sys.argv[1])
```

Run: `python test.py test.txt` and then `tail -f test.txt`. It shows appearing a-s.

Comment: The existence of a even single false means that there is no guarantee that lines will be read as a whole? --- Just verifying the logic.

Thanks for testing and finding a counterexample. When I tested on my server, it read whole lines, probably due to stuff I don't knowhow to configure.

Comment: @Dingfeng Quek: I assume it is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the man page:

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --follow=descriptor are equivalent
```

so that implies you'll see each character as it's appended, not just on new line. However, I imagine tail employs some kind of flushing strategy, so what you see may depend on how fast the file is being updated. I can only suggest you experiment a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not helpful. When I open 2 shells, on shell 1 I do `tail -f filename` and on shell 2 I do `echo 'hi' >>filename`, it shows in shell1. When in shell 2 I do `vi filename`, write some data, and then save, it doesn't. So there is no live following: it follows the file descriptor. If you want live following by periodic refresh, use `tail --follow=name filename`.

Comment: @Konerak - I don't see how not helpful. It prompted you to experiment, just as I suggested. I didn't know the answer, but I think it's reasonable to suggest how one might go about finding one. I think a DV is pretty harsh here.

Comment: It might be hard, but I'm following the question so if your answer improves, I'll change the vote. This is, imho, not an **answer**, at best a comment that prompts one to experiment ;)

Comment: @helpful? - I think it's repeating the question, with a detail I left out. 0 for votes seems appropriate.


Yes, my concern really is about flushing, buffering, and other IO stuff that I am not aware of; I inherited a legacy program which assumes that the lines are whole, but such assumptions are fragile.

What if it fails only when the read (of 0.001s every 3 seconds) coincides with the write (of 0.001s every 1.2 seconds)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that there is buffering.

Tail will probably do buffering, but the source may well be linebuffering. If the source is under your control, try to disable output buffering and see how that goes